# How to change the spinner text color while spinner set on the toolbar in android?

Tags: android, spinner

Explanation:
           I have spinner widget on the toolbar in my activity.Which added from the menu.xml in onCreateOptionMenu() method.I set the data into the spinner.How can i change the spinner text color while i set the spinner from menu.xml file in android?

Here is my menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="@string/spinner"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java while i get the menu.xml items

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem item=menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);

    Spinner spinner_month=(Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    adapter_month=new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item ,months_list);
    spinner_month.setAdapter(adapter_month);
    return true;
}
```

How can i change the color of the spinner text?Default color is black.

Please, help me to solve out this problem.

Comment: You can use your own layout instead of android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item with textview within and can set text color there.

Comment: But the problem is how can i change the background of spinner like popupoverlay style???

Comment: add background to textview

Answer (score 4):

**spinner_item.xml:**

Give your customized color and size to text in this file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:gravity="left"  
android:textColor="#FF0000"         
android:padding="5dip"
/>
```

Now use this file to show your spinner items like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
```

You don't need to set the drop down resource. It will take spinner_item.xml only to show your items in spinner.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own layout for spinner items with id say `my_spinner_item`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:padding="5dip"
    />
```

Then create the spinner object like this:

```
adapter_month=newSpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
    android.R.layout.my_spinner_item ,months_list);
```

In your resource xml fine `my_spinner_item.xml` you can now define the color of the text displayed in the spinner with `android:textColor`

Answer (score 0):

Create you `layout` with specify textcolor &  use your own layout instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my example and for change spinner popup background use this

"android:popupBackground="@android:color/holo_green_dark"

custom_toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

     <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:padding="5dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private Spinner spinner;
     String[] list=new String[]{"Android","iPhone","Windows"};
     private  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // change spinner item layout.
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item,list);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
}
```

Output
[custom toolbar with custom spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEESe.png)